# How to apply opacity to just a portion of the image?

Tags: theming

I've got a slideshow on the homepage which consists of an image and with text in front of it, in the bottom half of the image. I would like to apply opacity to the lower part of the image. Is there a way to do this using css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the image with an absolutely positioned div:

Check here for the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JMBFS/37/)

[SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119327/css-or-javascript-to-highlight-certain-area-of-image-opacity)

Answer (score 0):

What I would have done is to add a new `div` or `span` element with the same background as the page, then absolute position it between the image and the text using `z-index`. How the CSS looks depends on your page layout and html structure, but note that all elements needs a `position` value for `z-index` to work.